# How to use Clean Architecture in Microservices?

Tags: microservices, clean-architecture

I just finished reading Uncle Bob's "Clean Architecture" and now wondering how to apply it in the context of microservices!

On one hand, I think that microservices fall in the "Framework-Drivers" layer since it's an implementation on top of use-cases (they are ways to serve use-cases.) This way, we focus on the core of the app (Entities and Use-cases) and stay flexible in the implementation of the outer layers (including microservices). But since each microservice can be maintained by a different developer/team of developers, they will have a bad time when use-cases change (harder to predict who will be impacted).

On the other hand, we can split our app into multiple microservices, decoupled from each other, and apply Clean Architecture inside each microservice. The pro of this approach is that we can focus on each microservice doing one thing, and doing it well. But the problem is that we started designing using technical separations (microservices) which violates the main Clean Architecture principle of focusing on the business. Also, it will be hard to not duplicate code if two microservices uses the same entity or use-case!

I think the first scenario is the best, but I would like to have feedback from fellow developers on the long-term benefits of both scenarios, and potential troubles.

Answer (score 11):

My two cents:

From Uncle Bob's [words](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/10/01/CleanMicroserviceArchitecture.html), "Micro-services are deployment option, not an architecture". Each micro-service should be deployable, maintainable by different teams (which can be in different geographical locations). Each team can choose their own architecture, programming language, tools, frameworks etc... **And forcing each team to use single/same programming language or tool or architecture does not sound good.** So each micro-service team must be able to pick their architecture.

How can each team code/maintain/deploy their own micro-service without conflicting with other teams code? This question brings us to how to separate micro-services. IMHO it should be separated on feature based (same principle applies to modularization of mobile application projects where independent teams should be able to work on separate modules/micro-services).

After separating micro-services, the communication between them is implementation detail. It can be done through web-socket/REST API etc... Inside each micro-service, if team decides to follow Clean Architecture, they can have multiple layers based on Clean Arch Principles (Domain/Core - Interface Adapters - Presentation/API & Data & Infrastructure). There can/will be duplicate codes on micro-services, which are OK for micro-services.

Answer (score 6):

As @lww-pai-long said in his answer here splitting based on the Domain responsibilities and DDD is in most cases the best solution. 
Still if you worked with a system using micro-services you soon realize that there are other things involved here as well.

**DDD Bounded Context as base for micro-services**

In most cases splitting your application to micro-services based on Bounded Context is the safe way to go here. From experience I would even say that in some parts of Domain you could go even further and have multiple micro-services per Bounded Context. Example would be if you have quite big part of Domain which represents one Bounded Context. Other example would be if you use CQRS for a particular Domain. Then you can end up having a Write/Domain and Views/Read micro-service. 
You can read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56668521/1775693) how you can split your Domain to micro-services.
It would be advisable as you said to "apply Clean Architecture inside each microservice".

> Also, it will be hard to not duplicate code if two microservices uses
>   the same entity or use-case!

This is something that you have to deal with when working with micro-services in most cases. Duplicating code and/or data across multiple micro-service is common drawback of working with micro-services. You have to take this into account as you on the other hand get isolation and independence of the micro-service and its database. This problem can be partly solved by using shared libraries as some sort of packages. Be careful this is not the best approach for all cases. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58788159/1775693) you can read about using common code and libraries across micro-services. Unfortunately not all advice's and principles from Uncle Bob's "Clean Architecture" can be applied when using micro-services.

**Non Domain or technical operation micro-services**

Usually if your solution is using micro-services you will more or less have micro-services which are not Domain specific but rather some kind of technical task's or non business operations directly. Example could be something like:

- micro-service for report generation
- micro-service for email generation and forwarding
- micro-service for authorization/permission management
- micro-service for secret management
- micro-service for notification management

These are not services which you will get by splitting your solution based on DDD principles but you still need them as general solution as they could be consumed by multiple other services.

**Conclusion**

When working with micro-services you will most of the time have a mixture of Domain specific and Domain agnostic micro-services. I think the Clean Architecture could be looked from a little different prospective when working with micro-services.

> On one hand, I think that microservices fall in the
>   "Framework-Drivers" layer since it's an implementation on top of
>   use-cases (they are ways to serve use-cases.)

It kind of does but it also falls into the other layers like Entities and Use Cases. I think it goes in the direction that if you work on Domain specific services this [Diagram](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) becomes the Architecture of each micro-service but not a concept above all micro-services. In the applications where I worked with micro-services each micro-service(the ones which are based on the DDD Bounded Context) had most of this layers if not all of them. The Domain agnostic services are an exception to this as they are not based on Domain Entities but rather on some tasks or operations like 'Create an Email', 'Create a PDF report from html template' or similar'.

Comment: I agree that a domain services can sometimes worth splitting again in a sub-sub-domain. I also agree that the possible duplication of code or library is a inevitable trade-off and in the worst case can become a dependency hell fest.  But regarding non domain or helper functionalities,IMHO those services can also be implemented as sidecars, i.e added by the [application operator](https://github.com/oam-dev/spec/blob/master/2.overview_and_terminology.md#roles-and-responsibilities), since there will be required everywhere, this way they can still be scale based on the domain services activity.

Answer (score 2):

*I think this question may be better on [Sofware Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) but I'll answer anyway.*

---

My approach would be to use DDD and define each microservice as a *Domain Services* grouping *Use Cases* semantically, then link *Domain Services* with *Bounded Context*.

Sam newman talk about the importance of separating microservice by domain abraction and not technical one in [Building Microservices](https://samnewman.io/books/building_microservices/)

The point he makes basically is that defining scaling strategies for microservice based on subdomain will better match the "real live" constraints observed on the production system than using technically based microservice and try to defined a abstract strategy.

And if you look at how something like Kubernetes works it seems to push to that direction. A *pod* end up being a microservice with multiple containers defined as a complete stack matching a sub-domain if the overhaul application.

It then gets easier in an e-commerce application, for example, to scale the *Payment* service independently of the *Cart* service based on customer activity than to scale the web services independently of the job queues in an abstract way.

The way those *Bounded Contexts* will communicate, *i.e request based or event based*, depends on the the specific relation between them. To use the same example a *Cart* may generate an event that will trigger the *Payment*, while the same *Cart* may need to request the *Inventory* before validating the order.

And at the end of a day those Domain Services* and *Bounded Contexts* can be implemented the same when starting with a monolith, even the *Bounded Contexts* communication can be. The underlying communication protocol becomes an implementation detail that can easily(kinda) be switch when transitioning to a distributed a.k.a microservices architecture.