# How to Communicate between .Net Core 2.2 Web API Microservices

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices

I am working on .net core 2.2 Microservices architecture,

I have 2 different Microservices, `Service1`, `Business_Service`
Now, for some API Call to Business_Service, I want to call Sevice1,
I want to communicate between these Microservices,

I have two alternatives,

```
1. Expose Web API in Service1 & Make HTTP API hit from Business_Service for every request.
2. Use RabbitMQ / ZeroMQ to communicate between these layers.
```

I have implemented 1st alternative & it is working fine.

But I think it will be having the overhead of calling the entire HTTP protocol stack.

can you suggest what will be suitable for this case?
Or any alternative for this situation?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you haven't get my point, It's not about Name, Mobile Number, there may be the case when I need the information of all the users, with their departments, their writes, permissions, and many more. Does it good to store it in every claim?

Comment: Here you can read about ways how micro-service can communicate between each other: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649230/micro-services-architecture-loose-coupling-complications/56656955#56656955