# Authentication & Authorization in Micro services environment

Tags: microservices

All of my Micro Services, checking client access token validation using Rest API call to against my Authorization micro service which make a coupling between all the services to the Authorization Micro Service. The problem is that the token located only on the Authorization service Database. Is there a better way to do it instead of rest api?

Usually i prefer amqp over Rest API to avoid coupling but i can't see other option. Could someone help with that?

Comment: @xargs - Could you help?

Comment: if you are running your services privately then you can validate the token at gateway only. i don't see a problem anyway if your services are validating token from auth microservice. as long as auth api can scale and be deployed independently it should be ok. preferably try to use api gateway and validate at once.